# Specifying a date field in Elasticsearch Index Template

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, elasticsearch-mapping

I've tried updating my index template to allow an epoch and ISO8601 date format directly at the mapping level in Elasticsearch, which should override the @timestamp field.  So far I've had no luck.  My template can be viewed here http://pastebin.com/1DCT6GfM.

Essentially, once I parse the json logs are parsed by Logstash, Elasticsearch should recognized those fields and automatically update the @timestamp field.  Examples of potential log events include:

`{"timestamp_epoch": "1432146610", "message": "This is a test message to test epoch timestamp events", "category": "testing", "country": "EU"}`

or

`{"timestamp_iso8601": "2015-05-20T14:30:20-05:00", "message": "This is a test message to test epoch timestamp events", "category": "testing", "country": "US"}`

Please note that every other mapping in that template works fine except for `timestamp_epoch` and `timestamp_iso8601`.  I can tell those two mappings aren't taking affect because the @timestamp isn't updating to the proper value.

You can see a few of the raw sample Elasticsearch entries here: http://pastebin.com/HmtmNNAb

The type for **timestamp_iso8601** is updating to `date`, but it's not overriding the @timestamp field and **timestamp_epoch** set to **string** instead of **date**

I'd really appreciate if someone could clarify exactly what it is that i'm doing incorrectly.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the mapping for the index (`GET /my_index/_mapping`). Does it include what you expect it to for the timestamps fields?

Comment: I updated my original message above to clarify a bit.  The mapping for `timestamp_iso8601` is correct as `date` and the `timestamp_epoch` is incorrect as `string`.  Both fields still aren't updating the main `@timestamp` field.